# what do I need to do on all hosts after setting up internal DNS

Tags: dns

this must be a dumb question. I just setup a Raspberry Pi running DietPi as an internal DNS server. What do I need to do for the hosts in my network to use it?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using DHCP in your network, then you have to configure your DHCP server to provide the IP address of your internal DNS server to hosts.

If you configure networking in your hosts manually, you need to specify the IP address of your internal DNS server in TCP/IP settings on each host. How exactly to do it, of course depends on the OS. In Ubuntu, you have a field to specify DNS servers in IPv4 tab of your network connection's properties window.

Comment: Thank you so much! So I'll need to point my router to provide the internal DNS server. Hmm, got to read more on this subject.